# How to add alphabet increment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql

i have this table

| series | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1975 | 1 |
| 1985 | 1 |
| 1995 | 2 |
| 2000 | 2 |

what we trying to achieve is we add alphabet increment where id is same, example series will be 1975A, 1985B, and then 1995A 2000B when id is same, it is possible to do that? in query or in c# mvc code?

Comment: what about after nZ where n is a number

Comment: Yes, it is possible via a single c# for/foreach loop to initialize all your alphabet incremented strings assuming your collection is already sorted by Id. Perhaps you can store the calculated string in database and only recalculate for all entries of same id if there are any insertion/removal/update.

Comment: so firsrt you select collection where id same and add alphabet increment then store it in database, repeat?

Comment: What if there will be more items with the same id than letters in the English alphabet?

Comment: Yes that's possible. Please show the code you've tried so we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below query.
At first,

1. I have added row number par group/ partition
2. Then as we know CHR(65)='A', Thus I have added 64 + auto row_rumber
3. And Convert to CHAR.
4. Add result with series field.

```
SELECT
CONCAT
(
series , 
CHR(64 + CAST ( row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY id order by id) AS integer )) 
)
,id from table1
```

[image]

Comment: it is possible when id have only 1 series and alphabet increment did not added?